# KDE 4.7.3: how to remember ssh key passphrase in konsole?

Tags: kde, ssh, konsole

I am using latest KDE in Kubuntu 11.10, I have ssh keys added protected by a passphrase which is prompted every time I try to establish ssh connection. In Gnome it would pop up a GUI window where I entered this passphrase once after login, and it never asked for it later on. How can I make KDE remember my passphrase?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the terminal, then probably [this](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/) might be a solution for you.

The idea is to add the code they state into your .bashrc. Thus, you will need to input it only once at login, the same way you used to have while under ubuntu.

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you should use `ssh-agent`. 
Use the command `ssh-agent bash`
See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once) for more information.

Comment: that link has a bad accepted answer, but the correct answer is down further on the page.