# Enter SSH passphrase once

Tags: ssh, git, passphrase

### Before upgrade

When I was running `git clone git@...` (using ssh) once per computer restart a window dialog appeared containing a textbox for inserting my SSH passphrase and confirmed with OK. Then the passphrase was no longer required until the next start of my system.

### After upgrading to 13.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 that window doesn't appear anymore but a message in terminal appears:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

...every time when cloning a git repository this appears.

How can I fix this? I want to enter my passphrase only once.

Comment: I think you have to use the `ssh-add` command for that. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried `ssh-agent bash` + `ssh-add`. That works only for few minutes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after all. I think it may be a conflict between OpenSSH's ssh-agent and the Gnome Keyring Daemon.

Comment: @devius See if my answer helps you: http://askubuntu.com/a/362287/148451

Comment: Related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ssh/+bug/1247169

Comment: Add `AddKeysToAgent yes` to .ssh/config works for me.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

> Update: seems to be a bug from 13.10:
>
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ssh/+bug/1247169

---

Anyway running the following commands the problem was fixed for me:

### How to fix

I fixed this by entering the following commands:

```
$ ssh-agent bash
```

This creates a new bash process that allows you to add private keys. When adding a new private key you will be prompted for the passphrase once and only once.

And then:

```
$ ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

...where `username` is your username. You can do the same using `$USER` variable:

```
$ ssh-add /home/$USER/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Alternatively, just use `~` for your home directory.

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And the problem was fixed.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem at all. It only adds the identity to the agent until you exit out of the terminal. If you open a new terminal you have to `ssh-add` again.

Comment: @devius Yes, seems to be a bug. But, the commands above fixed my problem...

Comment: So to clarify: With this "fix" you will only not have to type in the passphrase in that terminal again. The moment you open a new terminal - you will have to give the passphrase again.

Comment: I tried `$ ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa` (without `ssh-agent bash`) and it worked for me even after reopening the terminal. But the complete solution for me was this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/4246809/532252. Everything is ok even after rebooting the machine.

Comment: I just typed ssh-add in the terminal.  No need to switch to ssh-agent bash or specify an id_rsa file

Comment: In fact you just need to run `ssh-agent` or an alternative *for the session*, not for one shell.

Comment: `$ eval $(ssh-agent)` then `$ ssh-add /path/to/key`

Comment: For me it doesn't fix the problem, because if I close the terminal and reopen it, then it still  asks for a passphrase.

Answer (score 104):

## Short answer

Use [AddKeysToAgent](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#AddKeysToAgent) and add the following to your `.ssh/config` at the beginning:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

and run git/ssh/... If it's not enough, check your ssh version and check that ssh-agent is loaded with these instructions:

## 1) Check the openssh version

Firstly check that your ssh version, it must be [greater of equal to 7.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2):

```
ssh -V
```

## 2) Edit the config file

If it's the case just add in your `.ssh/config` one line at the beginning:

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Other options are `no` (the default), `yes`, `confirm` (optionally followed by a time interval), `ask` or a time interval.

## 3) Check if ssh-agent is already open

Usually distributions automatically load an ssh-agent. To check it, run

```
ps aux | grep -v grep | grep ssh-agent
```

If you don't see any line containing it, you need to load it by running:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Note that this enable the agent only on the current terminal, so to enable it everywhere, you can try to add this line in your `~/.profile` file and reboot.

Comment: `AddKeysToAgent yes` is the canonical post-2016 answer – and *exactly* what most modern users are grepping about for. It's mid-2017. Ubuntu >= 16.04 (*Xenial Xerus*) is now a reasonable assumption. Most OpenSSH installations in the wild now support this option. Ad-hoc shell script kludges of the sort advocated by every other answer to this question are so... *passé*. `</sigh>`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: So this doesn't work for me, in 18.04. To be clear this works once _per session_, but it doesn't make it persist over restarts.

Comment: @SCdF you probably need to add `eval $(ssh-agent)` to your `.bashrc` using something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217223/355088

Answer (score 45):

[This Atlassian document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=277252540) ([archive.org backup](https://web.archive.org/web/20150530093155/https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=277252540)) fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition:

Just add this values into your `.bashrc` file:

```bsh
SSH_ENV=$HOME/.ssh/environment
   
# start the ssh-agent
function start_agent {
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent..."
    # spawn ssh-agent
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    echo succeeded
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    /usr/bin/ssh-add
}
   
if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
     . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
     ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

And after logging in, it asks for password only once and it caches. You don't need to enter it each time.

Comment: // , I'll have to try this out, but it looks good.

Comment: This seems to work on other distros, like I just successfully used this answer on Sabayon Linux.

Comment: Thanks! This solution worked for me on an ubuntu system where the gnome-keyring-daemon didn't work because of dbus-daemon issues. Specifically, I was getting these errors "** Message: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11" and after setting the display environment variable I got "** Message: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed."

Comment: This needs more upvotes, fixes the problem on virtualized Ubuntu 16.04 fine.

Comment: This fixes the problem for me on Bash for Windows as well. I tried launching Bash multiple times and it remembered the passphrase. Haven't tried a restart yet.

Comment: after trying all the other solutions, this worked for me. This should be the solution to the OP

Comment: this should be what KDE does by default.

Comment: Confirmed working on 18.04 machine ! Neat answer +1

Answer (score 21):

A workaround for [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-ssh/+bug/1247169) is to add the following to the bottom of `~/.bashrc`

```
eval `gnome-keyring-daemon --start`
```

Comment: Shouldn't gnome keyring just be part of your session?

Comment: If you are talking about 'should', then This question shouldn't be here on first place, if everything is that perfect

Comment: Not sure if this belongs to `.bashrc`. Looks like you have to add it into some DE profile file

Answer (score 5):

I've spend far too long to get it running on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04. Finally, we need to start ssh-agent on spawning new console, but don't load a key then. Load key upon first usage and use `AddKeysToAgent`.

Add following at the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

```
SSH_ENV="$HOME/.ssh/agent-environment"

function start_agent {
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > "${SSH_ENV}"
    chmod 600 "${SSH_ENV}"
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
}

if [ -f "${SSH_ENV}" ]; then
    . "${SSH_ENV}" > /dev/null
    #ps ${SSH_AGENT_PID} doesn't work under cywgin
    ps -ef | grep ${SSH_AGENT_PID} | grep ssh-agent$ > /dev/null || {
        start_agent;
    }
else
    start_agent;
fi
```

> Note that `/usr/bin/ssh-add;` is deliberately missing here, comparing
> to [original script](https://askubuntu.com/a/634573/85717).

And add following at the end of `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
```

Comment: While this doesn't ask me for a passphrase on startup, it still askes me the first time using a git pull/push.

Comment: @MichaelCook this is desired behavior, as question author says "I want to enter my passphrase only once."

Answer (score 4):

Users of the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) can use this [script](https://gist.github.com/gerbsen/5fd8aa0fde87ac7a2cae) to do the same thing.

```
# content has to be in .config/fish/config.fish
# if it does not exist, create the file
setenv SSH_ENV $HOME/.ssh/environment

function start_agent                                                                                                                                                                    
    echo "Initializing new SSH agent ..."
    ssh-agent -c | sed 's/^echo/#echo/' > $SSH_ENV
    echo "succeeded"
    chmod 600 $SSH_ENV 
    . $SSH_ENV > /dev/null
    ssh-add
end

function test_identities                                                                                                                                                                
    ssh-add -l | grep "The agent has no identities" > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        ssh-add
        if [ $status -eq 2 ]
            start_agent
        end
    end
end

if [ -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" ] 
    ps -ef | grep $SSH_AGENT_PID | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        test_identities
    end  
else
    if [ -f $SSH_ENV ]
        . $SSH_ENV > /dev/null
    end  
    ps -ef | grep $SSH_AGENT_PID | grep -v grep | grep ssh-agent > /dev/null
    if [ $status -eq 0 ]
        test_identities
    else 
        start_agent
    end  
end
```

Comment: There is also https://github.com/danhper/fish-ssh-agent that users can install with `fisher`, instructions at link.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
vim ~/.profile

eval `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg`
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
export GPG_AGENT_INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you use azure .ppk file**

Just convert it to pem and add permission 400 with simple steps:

```
sudo apt-get install putty
puttygen <path_to_key>/keyname.ppk -O private-openssh -o <path>/aws_key.pem
sudo chmod 400 <path>/aws_key.pem
ssh -vi aws_key.pem ubuntu@<ip_address>
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the ssh-agent is started when the session X is opened, it is managed in the file /etc/X11/Xsession.options:

```
# cat /etc/X11/Xsession.options
# $Id: Xsession.options 189 2005-06-11 00:04:27Z branden $
#
# configuration options for /etc/X11/Xsession
# See Xsession.options(5) for an explanation of the available options.
allow-failsafe
allow-user-resources
allow-user-xsession
use-ssh-agent
use-session-dbus
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution is use [keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain).
[Man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/keychain.1.html).

> Keychain helps you to manage SSH and GPG keys in a convenient and secure manner. It acts as a frontend to ssh-agent and ssh-add, but allows you to easily have one long running ssh-agent process per system, rather than the norm of one ssh-agent per login session.
>
> **This dramatically reduces the number of times you need to enter your passphrase.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu 18.04 or later, gnome keyring will launch ssh-agent and set the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable. You can always verify after reboot using the command `pgrep -af ssh-agent` to see if **ssh-agent** is running and if its launched by gnome keyring you should see the output like `214325 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh`

If NOT you can add the following to `.bashrc` before adding the **keychain** commands.

```bsh
eval `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --start --components=pkcs11,secrets,ssh,gpg`
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
export GPG_AGENT_INFO
```

To take advantage of storing the secrets in the gnome keyring, all we need is to install **Seahorse aka Passwords and Keys** from the Ubuntu software store using which we can add SSH keys and its passphrases using GUI.

Add the below section to SSH config file at `$HOME/.ssh/config` if not already present.

```
Host *  
    AddKeysToAgent yes
```

After adding the keys and its passphrases to the seahorse, [install keychain](https://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) and then add the following line to `.bashrc`.

```bsh
key_files=('~/.ssh/id_rsa1' '~/.ssh/id_rsa2')
# This will inherit the ssh-agent started by the gnome keyring and hence
# we don't need to enter passphrases after every reboot.
/usr/bin/keychain --agents ssh --inherit any --eval ${key_files[*]}
source "$HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh"
```