# How to enter ssh passphrase key once and for all

Tags: ssh, password, encryption, passphrase

I have set up a password-less setup for ssh that uses public key authentication to connect with desired remote server, everything has been working quite well.

I'm using passphrase to unlock the private key, using this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/634573/253251)— the problem is it asks password everytime I start my system.

I found this to be troublesome, I want to enter it only **once and for all** so the next time I boot up the session I won't have to enter it again, is there something like cached key that holds up my passphrase and works across session (also survive a reboot) ?

Would it be possible to achieve all of this whilst keeping my ssh passphrase intact ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You want to use `keychain`.

The `keychain` program manages an instance of the key cache program `ssh-agent`. When `ssh-agent` is started, two environment variables are created to be eval'd. Normally when the shell is closed where `ssh-agent` has been started, those environment variables are lost. The `keychain` program keeps track of those variables across logins and provides shell scripts in the `~\.keychain` directory.

There are several ways to run `keychain`, one method is manually from the command line. Each time you start the shell, use:

```
eval `keychain --eval`
```

This will find `ssh-agent` if it's running, and start it if it's not. Either way, using eval on `keychain` will set the necessary environment variables where you can add keys using:

```
ssh-add <private-keyfile>
```

If `private-keyfile` has a password, you will be prompted to enter that password during the execution of `ssh-add`, but as long as `ssh-agent` is running that will be the last time you need to enter the password for the private key.

Because the eval of `keychain` sets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable, any run of `ssh` will use the `ssh-agent` to accomplish the authentication.

Another suggestion is to add the `keychain` execution to your `.bashrc` file, as suggested in [this StackExchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75044/238508).

To terminate `keychain` just enter the command:

```
keychain --stop mine
```

or if you want to bring down all the instances of `ssh-agent`, enter the command:

```
keychain --stop all
```

Just a note, using services such as `ssh-agent` defeat the security of passworded private key files by storing those authenticated keys in memory. This is not safe, especially with memory side-channel attacks. If you're not interested in key security, the simpler solution is to remove the password on the private key as suggested by @vidarlo.

Comment: +1 I found this to work: You'll be asked for the passphrase just once at login. As per instructions on keychain site, I put in .bash_profile: eval `keychain --eval --agents ssh ssh_key1 ssh_key2` in - in my case I had 2 ssh keys - so I'll be asked for each one, but only once. In my .ssh config file also have a line under Host *  which is AddKeysToAgent but I don't know if that is needed.

Comment: I'm using this with Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2 on Windows. Once I've entered the passphrases once in one terminal, I can open other terminals and not be asked again. I can even close all terminals and open one and it still works, keychain puts a message in the terminal to say it found the keys (which I'd entered the passphrases for).

Comment: meta note: this answer does not answer the question but is a good answer. paradox?

Answer (score 8):

Run `ssh-keygen -p`. This will allow you to remove the passphrase set on the key. If no passphrase is set, it's stored in clear text, and you can use it without unlocking it:

```
$ ssh-keygen -p 
Enter file in which the key is (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter old passphrase: 
Key has comment ''
Enter new passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved with the new passphrase.
```

Simply press enter when prompted for passphrase to set no passphrase. After that, you can use your key freely.

Comment: I don't want to disable passphrase altogether, just wondering if it is possible to enter it only once and never have to enter it again.

Comment: That's effectively the same as disabling it...

Comment: @vidario No it's not the same as disabling it.  Removing the passphrase means that anyone who mistakenly gains access to the key would be able to use it without effort.  This is a *huge security risk* that is drastically different to using a software-based (or even hardware-based) key safe, mainly because it may be years before you discover that your key has been copied.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but it seems this is the best way. I still want to make it password protected, though.

Comment: this is not what the OP asked for and it introduces a security vulnerability which the OP's method's purpose was to avoid in the first place. You need to use a keychain instead. I would mark @John J. 's answer as accepted

Answer (score 7):

Simple answer is No.
That defeats the purpose (i.e. protection) if it's sustained across reboots.
You can however sustain it across login sessions and even across multiple terminals.

- If you want to sustain across login sessions but are OK to enter password once per terminal, then add `eval $(ssh-add)` to to `.bash_profile`
- If you want to do it once per system reboot, the install keychain, change your `~/.ssh/config` file to add keys to the keychain (`AddKeysToAgent yes`) and do the above step as well.